# Link options when redirecting

Tags: redirect

good day

When creating a new record in the component, a link is sent to the admin's mail

```
http: //localhost/index.php? option = com_aepetitions & view = editpetition & task = editpetition.edit & id = 4
```

But if the user is not authorized on the site, he is transferred to 1

```
com_aepetitions \ views \ editpetition \ tmpl \ default.php

http: //localhost/index.php? option = com_aepetitions & view = editpetition
```

In `com_aepetitions \ views \ editpetition \ tmpl \ default.php` made a login form with a redirect to the desired address,
but there is a problem - how can I get the parameter & id = 4
How do I get the id parameter after a redirect?
Reading JFactory :: getApplication () -> input-> get ('id') gives null

What is the chain in Joomla MVC when opening a link

```
http: //localhost/index.php? option = com_aepetitions & view = editpetition & task = editpetition.edit & id = 4
```

so that it was possible for an unauthorized user to write the id parameter somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  While you wait for feedback, please take our [tour].

Comment: How are you handling the redirect of the unauthorized admin? You should be able to arrange it with default permissions so that they are directed to the login form and redirected back to the original url automatically.

Comment: Capturing the url, base64 encoding it and then passing it via the redirect url and custom login form, or dropping it into the session and then pulling it back out is also an option.  Here is a post you may or may not find useful: https://joomla-tips.net/developer-tools/redirect-users-after-a-successful-login.html